# PHP - json_decode from url to variables

Tags: php, arrays, json

i had this url

```
 https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker
```

thats the json output of the first 2 (for example)

```
 {"BTC_BCN":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000018","lowestAsk":"0.00000018","highestBid":"0.00000017","percentChange":"0.00000000","baseVolume":"58.73610647","quoteVolume":"328275043.97652394","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00000019","low24hr":"0.00000017"},"BTC_BELA":{"id":8,"last":"0.00001191","lowestAsk":"0.00001191","highestBid":"0.00001174","percentChange":"0.13536701","baseVolume":"6.33896473","quoteVolume":"572949.02508918","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00001200","low24hr":"0.00001033"},
```

now i want to get all datas to varialbles. Like... $curreny = xxx; $last = xxx,..

i have tried it with that..

```
$url = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
$keys = array_keys((array)$obj);

foreach($keys as $result) {
$marketname = $result; }
```

that works for the first level .
then i get a list of all currencies. But.. how can i get all other data to the currency?

a second foreach? like..

```
 foreach($result[$marketname] as $result2) { }
```

doesn't make sense, i think!?

i would like to have it in that form

$currency = BTC_BCN;
$last = 0.00003223;
and so on..

Any idea?

Comment: Show an example of the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
$keys = array_keys((array)$obj);
for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++)
{
    echo 'Currency <strong>'.$keys[$i].'</strong>, last <strong>'.$obj[$keys[$i]]['last'].'</strong><br>';
}
?>
```

You already done all job of getting the information, just needed to use it :D

Use `print_r($variable)` to see what you have in an array and what indexes it has.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use array_keys.
You can use foreach to keep track of the key.

```
//$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = '{"BTC_BCN":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000018","lowestAsk":"0.00000018","highestBid":"0.00000017","percentChange":"0.00000000","baseVolume":"58.73610647","quoteVolume":"328275043.97652394","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00000019","low24hr":"0.00000017"},"BTC_BELA":{"id":8,"last":"0.00001191","lowestAsk":"0.00001191","highestBid":"0.00001174","percentChange":"0.13536701","baseVolume":"6.33896473","quoteVolume":"572949.02508918","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00001200","low24hr":"0.00001033"}}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

Foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    Echo "in ".$key . " last is ". $val['last'] ."\n";
}
```

Output is:

```
in BTC_BCN last is 0.00000018
in BTC_BELA last is 0.00001191
```

https://3v4l.org/UpkOm

---

If you want to use the items from the array as variables you can extract the variables.
I do not use this method myself as the values are in the array anyways.
I add this method because your question kind of implies that it's what you want.
On each iteration the variables will be overwritten, that is why this method is not recommended.
If one of the items do not have "last" all other variables will be overwritten with new data on the iteration except "last".
That means you have both new and old data in your variables at the same time.
My advice is to use the array and not to extract the variables.

```
$json = '{"BTC_BCN":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000018","lowestAsk":"0.00000018","highestBid":"0.00000017","percentChange":"0.00000000","baseVolume":"58.73610647","quoteVolume":"328275043.97652394","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00000019","low24hr":"0.00000017"},"BTC_BELA":{"id":8,"last":"0.00001191","lowestAsk":"0.00001191","highestBid":"0.00001174","percentChange":"0.13536701","baseVolume":"6.33896473","quoteVolume":"572949.02508918","isFrozen":"0","high24hr":"0.00001200","low24hr":"0.00001033"}}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

Foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    Extract($val);
    Echo $key ."\n";
    Echo $last ."\n";
    Echo $baseVolume ."\n\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/aZv1s